# How to execute delegate method once calling capturePhoto(with: , delegate: ) method

Tags: swift, xcode

This is my code.
When I click the **captureButton** it executes without error.
The purpose is to save a CIImage in captureProcessor.image

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let captureProcessor = captureProcess()

let session = AVCaptureSession()

let capturedPhotoOutPut = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    
@IBOutlet weak var previewOfCamera: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var imageShow: UIImageView!

@IBAction func captureButton(_ sender: Any)  {
    
captureProcessor.capturePhoto(capturedPhotoOutPut)

// getCGRectInfo()
// code above is to get CGRect info from captureProcessor.image
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configurePreview()

    }


func configureTheSession () -> Void {
   

    var videoInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    
    let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceType:[.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position:                                                                                                             .back).devices.first
    
    videoInput = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice!)
    
    session.beginConfiguration()
    
    session.sessionPreset = .hd1280x720
    
    session.addInput(videoInput)
            
    session.addOutput(capturedPhotoOutPut)
    
    session.commitConfiguration()
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        self.session.startRunning()
    }
    
    
}
```

And here is another class mentioned above

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class captureProcess: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate{
    
var image:CIImage!

func capturePhoto (_ photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput) {
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    settings.flashMode = .off
    photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
    
}

func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    
    
    let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation()

    image = CIImage(data: imageData!)
}
```

But if I add an action in @IBAction, e.g.  getInfo (comment in first chunk of code). Program will omit capturePhoto (it runs this line but doesn't execute the delegate) but executes getCGRectInfo first. The image variable is still empty. So the program will crash.

Is there any way to execute delegate method once the program run to capturePhoto line so that I can get the CIImage info properly

Comment: One thing missing from the code you posted - are you setting something to be the delegate? Maybe this can be done in IB (I don't use it that much) but somewhere I'd expect a `captureProcess.delegate = self` or something like that. (Also, the Swift way to name your classes is to begin the class name with a capital letter, like `CaptureProcess`. What is called "camel" names are for functions, like `photoOutput`.)

Comment: show your implementation for `getCGRectInfo`.  I suspect you don't really instantiate a `CaptureProcess` object and as a result there's nothing there to be called when it's time to call that delegate.